# How to turn a cifar10 dataset into a tensor

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network, tensor

I am trying to turn the cifar10 dataset into a tensor with

`trainset = datasets.CIFAR10(root='./data', train=True, download=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())`
but it continually returns false when I run it `torch.is_tensor(trainset)` function which means it's not a tensor and it also doesn't work for functions that require tensors in the code I'm running on.

I tried to print out the trainset with
`print(trainset)`
and I keep getting

> Dataset CIFAR10
> Number of datapoints: 50000
> Root location: ./data
> Split: Train
> StandardTransform
> Transform: ToTensor()

which means it's not yet a tensor.

How exactly can I convert the entire cifar10 dataset to a tensor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`trainset` is a Dataset instance and you do not convert it to a tensor. You should load the data and then transform it.

```
for i, data in enumerate(trainset, 0):
    do whatever
```