# How to convert CIFAR-10 to a tensor object

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, genetic-algorithm, torchvision

I'm attempting to build a CNN deep learning model utilizing a genetic algorithm to learn on CIFAR-10. I have so far found a few libraries, but I have mainly encountered pyGAD and some derivatives built on pyGAD. In the [examples of pyGAD implementations I could find](https://github.com/ahmedfgad/TorchGA/blob/main/pytorch_pygad_regression.py), the training step always utilizes a tensor object.

I know that a dataset item normally needs to be iterated, as answered in question [74258668](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74258668), but pyGAD does not appear to support processing such a method from what I could find.

Should I be using a different approach for this? Am I importing/processing the dataset wrong? Should I switch the genetic algorithm source from pyGAD to something else?

Note: I am using torchvision to import the CIFAR-10 dataset, and I have already converted the individual items from the dataloader version to tensor objects. I was previously following the [CIFAR-10 pytorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html).

Comment: I have since found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54897646). I think my question can be solved by converting to numpy as stated there, and then converting to a tensor object. Would this be a valid method?